# Enable Ignore Battery Optimization for Ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-intent, android-permissions

I want to Ignore Battery Optimization in our Ionic App, I have read about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

For this I have added **cordova-plugin-power-optimization** Plugin that will add `<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>` in AndroidManifest.xml,

Now I want to send Intent https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS for the user to go to settings screen where he can exclude battery optimization,

I am not sure how to achieve this with Ionic WebIntent plugin, which we generally use to send/receive Intents

So far I am trying this code but not sure how to set Options and startActivity
Can anyone help please, I am using Ionic 4 with Cordova 7.1.4

````
 this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)
               .then((result) => {
                   alert('Has permission?'+result.hasPermission)
                   this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)
                    .then((data)=>{
                        alert('request permission then' + data.hasPermission);
                        //what should go here in options and startActivity
                        const openOptions = {
                            action: this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            url: packageFileUrl,
                            type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
                        };
                      this.webIntent.startActivity(openOptions).then((data1)=>{alert('data:'+data1)});

                        })
                    .catch((data)=>{
                        alert('request permission catch'+data.hasPermission)
                })
                },
              );```
````

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send Intent through WebIntent, Its just I need to use Constant value
"android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" in Action part of Intent Options, This constant values are mentioned on

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Also for url, I have used getPackageName() method of AppVersion Plugin and pass this in url section of Intent Options,Here appName contains package Name and getPackageName() method is called from constructor.

Also Type is not needed here.

```
private async IntentIgnoreBatteryOptimization(resolve, reject) {
    const openOptions = {
        action:'android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        url: 'package:'+this.appName
    };
    try{
        resolve(await this.webIntent.startActivity(openOptions));
    }
    catch(err){
       reject('Permission denied'+err);
    }
}

async getPackageName(){
    if (this.device.isVirtual !== null) {
        await this.appVersion.getPackageName().then((result)=>{
            this.appName = result;
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can achieve this scenario by using the ionic Cordova native settings, in which you can pass `battery_optimization` and the native device will lead you to the battery optimization area.